# tar to pipe but keep -v verbose output separate from STDERR

Tags: tar, ksh, io

A normal tar command

```
tar cvf foo.tar ./foo >foo.out 2>foo.err
```

has three output IO streams

- archive data to foo.tar
- list of filenames to STDOUT (redirected into foo.out)
- error messages to STDERR (redirected into foo.err)

I can then inspect foo.err for error messages without having to read through the list of filenames.

if I want to do something with the archive data (pipe it through netcat or a special compression program) I can use tar's  `-f -` option thus

```
tar cvf - ./foo 2>foo.err | squish > foo.tar.S
```

But now my list of filenames is mixed in with my error messages because tar's `-v` output obviously can't go to STDOUT (that's where the archive data flows) so tar cleverly writes that to STDERR instead.

Using Korn shell, is there a way to construct a command that pipes the archive stream to another command but still capture the `-v` output separately from any error messages.

Comment: Are you familiar with `tee`? This seems like a pretty valid use case for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your system supports `/dev/fd/n`:

```
tar cvf /dev/fd/3 ./foo 3>&1 > foo.out 2>foo.err | squish > foo.tar.S
```

Which with AT&T implementations of `ksh` (or `bash` or `zsh`) you could write using *process substitution*:

```
tar cvf >(squish > foo.tar.S) ./foo > foo.out 2>foo.err
```

That's doing exactly the same thing except that this time, the shell decides of which file descriptor to use instead of `3` (typically above 9). Another difference is that this time, you get the exit status of `tar` instead of `squish`. On systems that do not support `/dev/fd/n`, some shells may resort to named pipes for that feature.

If your system doesn't support `/dev/fd/n` or your shell can't make use of named pipes for its process substitution, that's where you'd have to [deal with named pipes by hand](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181560).

Answer (score 6):

You have to use a named pipe for that.

First create one in the folder:

```
mkfifo foo.pipe
```

Then use that command:

```
tar cvf foo.pipe ./foo >foo.out 2>foo.err & cat foo.pipe >foo.tar
```

**Notice:** the `cat`-part, can now also be `gzip` or whatever, that can read from a pipe:

```
tar cvf foo.pipe ./foo >foo.out 2>foo.err & gzip -c foo.pipe >foo.tar
```

**Explanation:**

The output is written to the name pipe (`foo.pipe`), where another proccess (`cat`, `gzip`, `netcat`) reads from. So you don't loose the stdout/stderr channels for information.

Comment: Might be worth noting the implications of using a _named_ pipes. 1) best is to set a `umask 077` (or use a private temp dir) to prevent other processes reading or writing to it (on many systems, named pipes, like other files are created world-readable by default), 2) you need to ensure the named pipe is used only by each instance of your script (again a one-off private temporary directory helps) 3) That means you need to clean-up afterwards or if interrupted.

Comment: +1 - I like this answer. Unfortunately for me, there's some weirdness in named pipes on my (old) system that makes them unreliable when I try this.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I think it can sometimes be easier to clean up first, like: `p="/tmp/pipe$$"; mkfifo "$p"; (read na; cmd[s]...) <>"$p" & (echo;rm "$p"; cmd[s]...) >"$p"`

Answer (score 5):

GNU tar's [`--index-file` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_22.html#g_t_002d_002dindex_002dfile) works well:

```
tar cvf - ./foo 2>foo.err --index-file=foo.out | squish > foo.tar.S
```